# Как заставить линковщик использовать .dll файлы

Tags: ubuntu, компиляция, сборка, компоновщик

Столкнулся с такой странной проблемой... есть проект, он собирается как под Ubuntu  так и под Windows, но работаю я под **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** работал работал себе и вдруг решил перейти на **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**, установил компилятор `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` вроде все собирается и запускается, решил я ради пробы перенести на Windows и вуаля он затребовал не **.dll** расширение, а **.lib** расширение, чем меня сильно смутил, решил пойти дальше и проверить на 20.04 как он собирается, собирается проект из **.dll** файлов, я прежде чем собрать удалил все **.lib**. При записи проекта на Windows  программа требует **.dll** файлы так же, НО как только я возвращаюсь на 22.04 LTS все возвращается на круги своя, проверка показала, что линковщик использует **не .dll** файлы, **а .lib**.

И вот вообщем у меня такой вопрос к знатокам, как сделать так, чтобы компилятор опять стал собираться не из .lib файлов, а из .dll файлов? Может какие флаги линковщику надо установить? Ну по крайней мере я ищу ключи компиляции которые мне помогут, но так пока и не нашел, компилятор стал что ли более тупым каким-то или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ вообще не по теме [Решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243524/cmake-find-library-matching-behavior). А если коротко, то в Cmake надо было добавить установку флага CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES, т.е. set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dll"), можно еще и так написать set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dll" ".lib"). Спасибо всем за помощь =)